# The reference is invalid or unsupported while adding reference to the project

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using Visual studio 2017, my solution explorer for Web Api shows that the dependencies are missing and getting information icon displayed. When I try to add reference, I am getting the error message as "The reference is invalid or unsupported".

Comment: Did you solve it? Where the assemblies targeting different versions of .NET?